# Unity transform.lookAt

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

`transform.LookAt(target.position);`

I'm trying to use this code to have a AI lookAt the enemies but it looks way to high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more information would be nice. How are the objects placed in the hierarchy? Is `target` a parent or a child object?

What `transform.LookAt` does is pointing the `transform.forward` at the target's position.

Can you try `transform.LookAt(Vector3(target.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, target.transform.position.z);`?

If that doesn't work, can you try adding `transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);`?

With the last code you can see the object moving towards the target. That way you are sure it's pointing the right direction. Maybe you think it's looking too high because your model is wrong.

Comment: well I'm looking at it and it seems that the object is scaled down and  it's looking as if it's not scaled down.